# How can I make a new scene fade in when a button is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fade

I have followed a tutorial from Brackeys (you can watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HwZQt94uHQ)) on how to fade between scenes. I followed the tutorial the best I could, but, when I run my scene, the scene fades in (which is not supposed to happen) and when I press the button, nothing happens (but the scene is supposed to change).

What is wrong with my code? How do I fix it so a new scene fades in when the button is pressed? Here is my code:

**changeScene.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class changeScene : MonoBehaviour {

public IEnumerator changeToGameScene () {

    float fadeTime =     GameObject.Find("managerObject").GetComponent<fadeScript>().BeginFade(1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(fadeTime);
    Application.LoadLevel("gameScene");

}

}
```

**fadeScript.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class fadeScript : MonoBehaviour {


// All Variables
public Texture2D fadeOutTexture;
public float fadeSpeed = 0.8f;

private int drawDepth = -1000;
private float alpha = 1.0f;
private int fadeDirection = -1;

void OnGUI () {

    alpha += fadeDirection * fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(alpha);

    GUI.color = new Color (GUI.color.r, GUI.color.g, GUI.color.b, alpha);
    GUI.depth = drawDepth;
    GUI.DrawTexture ( new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height),     fadeOutTexture );
}

public float BeginFade (int direction) {

    fadeDirection = direction;
    return (fadeSpeed);

}

void OnLevelWasLoaded () {

    BeginFade (-1);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try placing a panel on top of the scene.
Then, using an animator component, create a new animation where the opacity decreases. In fact, you can make the button call this animation. At the end of the animation you could add an event to call a function that will destroy the panel.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I was hoping for some help with the code, but your way did work, so I accepted your answer anyways :)